# How do you configure WODM to use Java SE Execution Unit (XU) with Tomcat?

Tags: ibm-odm

I have read the instructions and have deployed the Rules Execution Server application on Tomcat 7 along with database connectivity.  I can log into the console to see the rules.  However, Tomcat does not have an XU .rar like WebSphere and the other application servers.  The instructions mention that Tomcat should use "Java SE Execution Unit (XU)", but the instructions for setting this up only include the 3 steps below.  I do not understand how to use the steps below to create "Java SE Execution Unit (XU)".  Any assistance is appreciated.  I would like for the Java SE XU to run as a part of Tomcat.

1. Set the executionserver.home property:
   /executionserver"/>
2. Import the classpath-executionserver.xml file:
3. Set the path for the executionserver.j2se.classpath property.
   The execution.j2se.classpath property defines all the JARs needed to execute Rule Execution Server on Java SE.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  We modified the code to use the standalone version instead of it being based on WebSphere.